# Como ordenar lista com objeto complexo por uma de suas propriedades?

Tags: c#, .net, classificação

Estou com uma lista de objetos e quero ordenar a lista por uma das propriedades (Desc do tipo string), como faço isso?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    // Várias outras propriedades
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Foo> objetos = Program.PreencheObjetos();

        objetos.Sort();
    }

    public static List<Foo> PreencheObjetos()
    {
        // Retorna uma lista preenchida.
    }
}
```

Não consegui utilizar o Sort para fazer isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode trabalhar com ordenação usando o método `List<T>.Sort(IComparer <T>)` (documentação no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) implementando a interface `IComparer` (documentação no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) nas classes dos objetos que quer ordenar. Veja como:

#### Na classe dos objetos

```
public class ComparadorDoMeuObjeto: IComparer<MeuObjeto>  {
    int IComparer.Compare( MeuObjeto x, MeuObjeto y )  {
        if(x == null)
            return -1;
        if(y == null)
            return 1;

        return x.PropriedadeInterna - y.PropriedadeInterna ;
    }
}
```

#### Veja como implementar

```
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| Valor             | Significado        | 
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| menor que zero    | x é menor do que y | 
| zero              | x é igual a y      | 
| maior do que zero | x é maior do que y | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

#### Como fazer a ordenação

```
 List<MeuObjeto> objs= new List<MeuObjeto>();
 objs.Add(new MeuObjeto(1));
 objs.Add(new MeuObjeto(2));
 objs.Add(new MeuObjeto(3));
 objs.Add(new MeuObjeto(4));

 ComparadorDoMeuObjeto comparador = new ComparadorDoMeuObjeto();

 // Com objeto IComparer
 objs.Sort(comparador);
 // Com Lambda para fazer a mesma coisa (parâmetros do IComparer)
 objs.Sort((x, y) => x.PropriedadeInterna  - y.PropriedadeInterna);
```

Comment: Como seria para ordenar uma objeto complexo, como por exemplo, Categoria?

Comment: Alfabeticamente? Numéricamente?

Por favor, coloque aqui uma resposta com sua tentativa de usar este modelo no seu objeto e um modelo simples de objeto para eu poder ver. Pode ser um link para um gist do github também...

Answer (score 12):

Podes usar linq para isso:

```
objetos = objetos.OrderBy(o => o.Desc).ToList();
```

ou passando uma função no .Sort()

```
objetos.Sort((o1,o2) => o1.Desc.CompareTo(o2.Desc));
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente usar Linq:

```
    var objetosEmOrdem = (from o in objetos
                          orderby o.Desc
                          select s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o método `Sort` passando um delegate `Comparison<T>`.

```
objetos.Sort((x, y) => x.Desc.CompareTo(y.Desc));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Veja se é isto que você quer

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

    // Várias outras propriedades
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Foo> objetos = Program.PreencheObjetos();

        objetos.OrderBy(a => a.Nome);
        objetos.OrderBy(a => a.Codigo);
        objetos.OrderBy(a => a.Sobrenome);

        objetos.OrderByDescending(a => a.Nome);
        objetos.OrderByDescending(a => a.Codigo);
        objetos.OrderByDescending(a => a.Sobrenome);
    }

    public static List<Foo> PreencheObjetos()
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Foo() { Codigo = i, Nome = "Nome " + i, Sobrenome = "Sobrenome " + i });

        }

        return list;

    }
}
```

Comment: As chamadas a OrderBy e OrderByDescending não ordenam a lista, elas retornam um resultado ordenado. Você deveria pegar o valor das ordenações em outra variável, não apenas chamá-la (como ocorre com o método Sort de List<T>).