# Como ordenar uma lista de objetos por DUAS propriedades

Tags: c#, .net, classificação

Nesse tópico: [Como ordenar lista com objeto complexo por uma de suas propriedades?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5083/como-ordenar-lista-com-objeto-complexo-por-uma-de-suas-propriedades) é explicado como ordenar por uma propriedade, mas como ordenar por duas?

Levando em conta a seguinte classe produto:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| Produto                                | 
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| Código            | int                | 
| Nome              | string             | 
| Preço             | double             | 
| Categoria         | Categoria          | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

E a classe categoria

```
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| Categoria                              | 
+-------------------+--------------------+ 
| Código            | int                | 
| Nome              | string             | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

E imaginando uma lista de produtos.

Como posso ordenar a lista por ordem alfabética do nome da sua categoria, seguido por ordem alfabética do próprio nome? É possível usar o `IComparer`?

Comment: Você não poderia usar LINQ?

Comment: Desconheço essa biblioteca, ela já tem uma função que faça isso nela?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faça com Linq, primeiro certifique-se de estar referenciando:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Em seguida use assim:

```
var ordenada = lista.OrderBy(m => m.Categoria.Nome).ThenBy(m => m.Nome);
```

Utilize a lista de retorno `ordenada` para percorrer. Assim:

```
foreach (var item in ordenada)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nome + " - " + item.Categoria.Nome);
}
```

Usando a sintaxe de query dessa forma é equivalente à anterior:

```
var ordenada = from m in lista
               orderby m.Categoria.Nome, m.Nome
               select m;
```

O `OrderBy` retorna uma lista do tipo `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` por isso só é possível usar o `ThenBy` depois do `OrderBy`. Se fosse necessário adicionar uma terceira propriedade ela viria com outro `ThenBy` e assim por diante.

Se você quisesse apenas alterar a lista original sem ter uma nova cópia ordenada, poderia fazer chamando o método `ToList()` dessa maneira:

```
lista = lista.OrderBy(m => m.Categoria.Nome).ThenBy(m => m.Nome).ToList();
```

Veja que também seria possível chamar o `OrderBy` duas vezes dessa forma:

```
var ordenada = lista.OrderBy(m => m.Nome).OrderBy(m => m.Categoria.Nome);
```

Seria necessário inverter a sequência, já que a lista inteira seria ordenada duas vezes (o que deve ser menos performático). Porém além de não ser muito semântico, também não é a forma de uso para qual o `OrderBy` foi projetado.

Comment: Agora que você editou ficou confuso, essa "var ordenada" é necessário? Quando eu precisar percorrer os objetos na lista, percorro a var ou a própria lista?

Comment: Desculpe, meu objetivo foi deixar a resposta mais completa. Mas você precisa sim usar a lista `ordenada` de retorno ao percorrer.

Comment: Como utilizar os valores dentro do `ordenada` ? Como percorrer os valores dentro dela?

Comment: Se você consegue percorrer os elementos de uma lista, nada muda. A lista `ordenada` contém o mesmo tipo de elementos da `lista` original.

Comment: Não consigo fazer: ordenada[0].Nome como fazia na lista original...

Comment: Hum, entendi... Faça isso: `var ordenada = lista.OrderBy(m => m.Categoria.Nome).ThenBy(m => m.Nome).ToList();` adicionando a chamada `ToList()` à lista retornada

Comment: Por alguma razão, retorna o erro  "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.", sendo que a lista Produtos está preenchida e posso usá-la

Comment: Ah, vi a fundo e percebi que a Categoria está nula, desculpe, erro meu!

Comment: Editei a resposta pra acrescentar outras opções que provavelmente atendam o que você precisa.